# Microsoft Access displays both months and years differences

Tags: ms-access, datediff, date-difference

How to display both years and months differences in access 2013. I've been using DateDiff formula, but it didn't work. It seems DateDiff only able to display one of the symbols (m, yyyy, or d). If DateDiff can't perform to display both months and years, is there are other codes available to do that?

Comment: Examples of one of my time differences : #Jan 2 2007#, #Jan 1 2016#. I want to use Access queries instead

Comment: From your comment difference will be `8 Year 11 Month 30 Days` Do you want this or some thing other.

Comment: Yes, i want something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this that simple because *DateDiff* shows difference between calendar years or months, not a timespan. The above attempt will return this sequence like this:

```
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2016-08  Y: 0  M: 6 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2016-09  Y: 0  M: 7 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2016-10  Y: 0  M: 8 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2016-11  Y: 0  M: 9 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2016-12  Y: 0  M: 10 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2017-01  Y: 1  M: 11 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2017-02  Y: 1  M: 0 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2017-03  Y: 1  M: 1 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2017-04  Y: 1  M: 2 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2017-05  Y: 1  M: 3 
d1: 2016-02  d2: 2017-06  Y: 1  M: 4
```

For a true timespan, you will have to use a function like this:

```
Public Function YearsMonthsDays( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByRef lngYears As Long, _
  Optional ByRef lngMonths As Long, _
  Optional ByRef lngDays As Long) _
  As String

' Returns the difference in years, months, and days between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS.
' 2010-03-30.

  ' Count of months in a calendar year.
  Const cintMonths  As Integer = 12

  Dim datDateMonth  As Date
  Dim intDays       As Integer

  ' No special error handling.
  On Error Resume Next

  lngMonths = Months(datDate1, datDate2)

  datDateMonth = DateAdd("m", lngMonths, datDate1)
  lngDays = DateDiff("d", datDateMonth, datDate2)
  intDays = Sgn(lngDays)
  If intDays <> 0 Then
    If intDays <> Sgn(DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2)) Then
      lngDays = 0
    End If
  End If

  lngYears = lngMonths \ cintMonths
  lngMonths = lngMonths Mod cintMonths

  YearsMonthsDays = CStr(lngYears) & " year(s), " & CStr(lngMonths) & " month(s), " & CStr(lngDays) & " day(s)"

End Function
```

which uses this helper function:

```
Public Function Months( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full months between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of month counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased stepwise one month from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of months to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2010-03-30. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intMonths As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar months.
  intMonths = DateDiff("m", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a 1 month period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", intMonths, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", -intMonths, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of months to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of months as count of full 1 month periods.
  Months = intMonths - intDiff

End Function
```

Comment: So, if i want the display like what you did, i have to use VBA?

Comment: Yes. Copy and paste the code into a new module. Then you can use the expression `DateSpan: YearsMonthsDays([StartDate],[EndDate])`

Answer (score 0):

Only ran a few tests... I would clean it up a little more to account for the plurals when not needed but this should give you a good start:

```
   ' Calculate Years and Months Difference
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click()
        Dim intYears As Integer
        Dim intMonths As Integer
        intYears = (DateDiff("m", Me.txtDateStart, Me.txtDateEnd) / 12)
        intMonths = (DateDiff("m", Me.txtDateStart, Me.txtDateEnd) Mod 12)
        Me.lblDifference.Caption = intYears & " Years " & intMonths & " Months"
    End Sub
```

ADDITION ON TO NEW EXPLANATION:
I haven't tested it but in a query you should be able to do it the same way: Put these expressions in your column headers

```
TotalYears:=(DateDiff("m", [dtStartDate], [dtEndDate]) / 12)
```

In another Column Header:

```
TotalMonths:=TotalYears:=(DateDiff("m", [dtStartDate], [dtEndDate]) Mod 12)
```

I got it to work just fine. Here is how I applied it: 
[image]

And then you can see the results: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, is that using VBA? Well, actually what i want is using query. But that's okay. Anyway, how to use VBA? I've never tried that before

Comment: Look at my updated answer now that I have more detail on what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks again. But it still wrong in TotalMonths. And what is exactly ":=" used for? It can't be done in Access

Comment: It worked fine for me (see update) the only thing I changed about my version is that I wrapped it all in a Cint() so that it returns only Integers and not fractional values.

Comment: I still got some errors in TotalMonths. Everything turned out to be 0.

Comment: I tried again, and i got all the result is just same as years column. But in month column, it display negative (-). Well, have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you will get negative results if the Begingin period date is after the ending period date. i.e. DateDiff("m", "01/01/2017, "01/01/2016")

Comment: But i actually did this : DateDiff("m", '01/01/2016','01/01/2017')

Comment: Those are not dates. Use: `DateDiff("m", #01/01/2016#,#01/01/2017#)`. But if you just want a "calendar difference", you can use Anthony's expressions simplified. `Years: DateDiff("m", [DateStart],[DateEnd]) \ 12` and `Months: DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd]) Mod 12`. Note the backslash for integer division.